# Does instanton have spin?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-spin

Usually, we call instanton a "pseudoparticle", but does it have spin? I know the similar soliton--skymion does have a spin 1/2 (which actually depends on color number $N_{c}$).

I used a general argument, which is rotating instanton and seeing the change over phase, and reckoned that action's change is $\sim\frac{8\pi^{2}}{g^{2}}$, hand-waving. Thus, does it mean that instanton has no spin since the running coupling?

Comment: In my argument, I made a mistake that there is no phase factor in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a bosonic path integral (without Grassman variables), the statistics of solitons in your theory are determined by the topological terms in your action, e.g., a $\theta$-angle, a Wess-Zumino-Witten (WZW) term, a Chern-Simons (CS) term, and so on.
Note that a topological term is still imaginary after the Wick rotation to Euclidean signature, while a dynamical term becomes real and positive definite after that.
In particular, to have fermionic statistics, your topological term has to be spin, i.e., exists on spin manifolds and depends on the spin structure.
[More mathematically, it should be an element of $\tilde{\Omega}_{spin}^{\bullet}(-)$ that doesn't exist in $\tilde{\Omega}_{SO}^{\bullet}(-)$.]

For example, you mentioned skyrmions in 4D $SU(n_f)$ sigma models, which are infrared descriptions of 4D massless $n_f$-flavor $SU(N_c)$-color QCD.
In order to reproduce the 't Hooft anomaly of UV QCD theories, these IR sigma models must have WZW terms.
It is precisely these WZW terms that determine the statistics of skyrmions.
When $N_c$ is odd, these WZW terms are spin ones.
That's why you have bosonic skyrmions for even $N_c$ and fermonic skyrmions for odd $N_c$.

This is nothing but a sort of Witten effect.
My favorite way to understand this effect is the following.
Consider a Euclidean path integral on the spacetime $M\times S^1$. Then you have (at least) two different spin structures on $M\times S^1$.
For the anti-periodic spin structure, your partition function $\mathcal{Z}_{+}=\mathrm{Tr}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\beta H}$ describes a thermal canonical essemble.
For the periodic spin structure, your partition function $\mathcal{Z}_{-}=\mathrm{Tr}\,(-)^F\mathrm{e}^{-\beta H}$ describes the Witten index instead.
When you have a spin topological term, because it depends on the spin structure, you can have $\mathcal{Z}_+\neq\mathcal{Z}_-$ by a purely bosonic path integral, which means some quantum states are fermionic in your Hilbert space.
Then you should check which sector gives this contribution and you may find the fermionic statistics of solitons.

---

Now come back to your question on instantons.
First of all, in 4D theories, instantons do not contribute to quantum states in Hilbert spaces.
So it is rather meaningless to talk about its statistics since it's just a classical solution to the Euclidean equation of motion.
However, you can of course consider 5D theories.
Then instantons contribute to particles in Hilbert spaces.
In that cases, the 5D CS terms with odd levels are spin ones.
So perhaps, these instanton-particles can become fermions.
We must explicitly compute and check it (I don't remember the exact result, sorry).

---

**Edit:** Let me add the relationship between your rotating argument and my spin-structure argument.
Let's consider the spacetime $S^n\times S^1$.
Then the rotating map $(\vec{x},t)\mapsto (\mathrm{e}^{\,t\,\vec{n}\,\times}\,\vec{x},t)$ exchanges the two spin structures I mentioned.
Therefore, when the spin topological term gives a phase factor of $(-1)$ under this rotating map, we just have a phase factor of $(-1)$ between different spin structures.
So they precisely talk about the same thing.

---

**Edit 2:**
Note that dynamical terms cannot contribute to statistics since they are real in Euclidean signature.
So, actually, I don't quite understand how you obtain your phase factor.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. There is no phase factor. But I think your statement clarified what I really would like to ask. I do appreciate it!

Comment: Besides, I don't understand "However, you can of course consider 5D theories. The instantons contribute to particles in Hilbert spaces." clearly. The instanton mentioned here is "4D-instanton" which lies on boundary of 5D spacetime or is 5D-instanton?  Could you give an additional comment?

Comment: Suppose you have a 4D-instanton $A(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Then you can have a 5D soliton $A'(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\equiv A(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, i.e., it's invariant along the fifth dimension.